# Column sort reset of ascending/descending on 3rd click

Tags: slickgrid

Suppose we've a grid with sortable columns.

If a user clicks on a column, it gets sorted by 'asc', then if a user clicks the column header again, it gets sorted by 'desc', now I want similar functionality when a user clicks the column third time, the sorting is removed, i.e. returned to previous style, the css is changed back to normal/non-italic etc?

Answer (score 2):

Today I was trying to achieve same thing. I've skimmed through SlickGrid code but didn't find any 'Reset' function. So, I've tweaked the **slick.grid.js** v2.2 a little bit.

Basically you just need to add a new array - 'latestSortColumns' which will store sort columns state (deep copy of internal SlickGrid sortColumns array).

```
var latestSortColumns = [];
```

Optionally add new setting to opt-in for sort reset.

```
var defaults = {
  (...),
  autoResetColumnSort: false
};
```

Change setupColumnSort to reset sort after third click on column's header.

```
function setupColumnSort() {
  $headers.click(function (e) {
    // temporary workaround for a bug in jQuery 1.7.1 (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11328)
    e.metaKey = e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey;

    if ($(e.target).hasClass("slick-resizable-handle")) {
      return;
    }

    var $col = $(e.target).closest(".slick-header-column");
    if (!$col.length) {
      return;
    }

    var column = $col.data("column");
    if (column.sortable) {
      if (!getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit()) {
        return;
      }

      var sortOpts = null;
      var i = 0;
      for (; i < sortColumns.length; i++) {
        if (sortColumns[i].columnId == column.id) {
          sortOpts = sortColumns[i];
          sortOpts.sortAsc = !sortOpts.sortAsc;
          break;
        }
      }

      **if ((e.metaKey || (options.autoResetColumnSort && latestSortColumns[i] != null && latestSortColumns[i].sortAsc === !column.defaultSortAsc)) && options.multiColumnSort) {**
        if (sortOpts) {
            sortColumns.splice(i, 1);
            **latestSortColumns.splice(i, 1);**
        }
      }
      else {
        if ((!e.shiftKey && !e.metaKey) || !options.multiColumnSort) {
          sortColumns = [];
        }

        if (!sortOpts) {
          sortOpts = { columnId: column.id, sortAsc: column.defaultSortAsc };
          sortColumns.push(sortOpts);
        } else if (sortColumns.length == 0) {
          sortColumns.push(sortOpts);
        }
      }

      setSortColumns(sortColumns);

      if (!options.multiColumnSort) {
        trigger(self.onSort, {
          multiColumnSort: false,
          sortCol: column,
          sortAsc: sortOpts.sortAsc}, e);
      } else {
        trigger(self.onSort, {
          multiColumnSort: true,
          sortCols: $.map(sortColumns, function(col) {
            return {sortCol: columns[getColumnIndex(col.columnId)], sortAsc: col.sortAsc };
          })}, e);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Store new state after every sort change in latestSortColumns:

```
function setSortColumns(cols) {
  sortColumns = cols;

  var headerColumnEls = $headers.children();
  headerColumnEls
      .removeClass("slick-header-column-sorted")
      .find(".slick-sort-indicator")
          .removeClass("slick-sort-indicator-asc slick-sort-indicator-desc");

  $.each(sortColumns, function(i, col) {
    if (col.sortAsc == null) {
      col.sortAsc = true;
    }
    var columnIndex = getColumnIndex(col.columnId);
    if (columnIndex != null) {
      headerColumnEls.eq(columnIndex)
          .addClass("slick-header-column-sorted")
          .find(".slick-sort-indicator")
              .addClass(col.sortAsc ? "slick-sort-indicator-asc" : "slick-sort-indicator-desc");
    }
  });

  **for (var i = 0; i < sortColumns.length; i++)
      latestSortColumns[i] = { columnId: sortColumns[i].columnId, sortAsc: sortColumns[i].sortAsc };**
}
```

That's all, should work now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I call to reset all columns back to their original order.

It requires one of columns to be set up as not sortable.
In the example below I use the first column of the table, columns[0], which has the field id "locus".

```
function removeSorting() {
  columns[0].sortable = true;
  $('.slick-header-columns').children().eq(0).trigger('click');
  columns[0].sortable = false;
  // clear other sort columns
  grid.setSortColumns( new Array() );
}
```

Then in the typical dataView.sort() function you make an exception for this column:

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e,args) {
  var cols = args.sortCols;
  dataView.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
    for( var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++ ) {
      var field = cols[i].sortCol.field;
      // reset sorting to original indexing
      if( field === 'locus' ) {
        return (dataRow1.id > dataRow2.id) ? 1 : -1;
      }
      var value1 = dataRow1[field];
      var value2 = dataRow2[field];
      if( value1 == value2 ) continue;
      var sign = cols[i].sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
      return (value1 > value2) ? sign : -sign;
    }
    return 0;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Will the table always be sorted in some order on some column?

If not then you'll have to store a lot of state the first time a column is clicked just in case you want to restore it after a third click.

Comment: I disagree, its like the poor hack approach. onSort's args.sortAsc only gives true or false, it should have an option for 'null' so that we can assume that its the third state?

Btw is there any way to RESET the sort order on all columns via api?